# FileOutputStream append alternative

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this method:

```
public static void write(String s, File f, String charset, boolean append) throws IOException {
    final FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(f, append);
    final OutputStreamWriter out = charset == null ? new OutputStreamWriter(fileStream) : new OutputStreamWriter(fileStream, charset);
    final BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(out);
    try {
        w.write(s);
    } finally {
        w.close();
    }
}
```

but I cannot use FileOuputStream anywhere in my application and I need to make this same write to output stream. How can I change this method so that it's doing the same without using FileOuputStream and what is the purpose of append (will merge both files) ? I'm using this on google app engine so writing on the file system is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment and some classes are blacklisted.

Comment: Append means that the the write calls will write at the end of existing file instead of overwriting its content. If you are not allowed to use FileSystem that you will not be able to write to file and there is no way arround (whole point of black listing it).  If you are asking about writing to an OutputStream (which you are given externally, is an over the wire connection and etc), just use the same code but starting from the given stram instead of fileOutputStream.

Comment: AppEngine doesn't let you write to the file system. So you'll have to store your data elsewhere: in the database, or in the blobstore, or using another external storage web service. Read the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage. Regarding what `append` does, once again, it's explain in the javadoc. Read it.

Comment: @Zielu Yes the goal is to return responce with this file as downloadble file. So yes I should change this somehow to write to output stream. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that changing the code will help you as **AppEngine generally does not support file system writes**.

You can change it to use `URL` or `FileChannel` but that would not help.

Comment: The result file output stream is returned as download file. I'm gonna try this tomorrow thanks